# What's the big-O of this code?

Tags: java, sorting, methods, big-o, nested-loops

Could somebody please help me find the big-O of this code? I've already tried to calculate it but I just don't understand how.

```
int n = //user input
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2){
        System.out.println(i * j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ask yourself how many iterations are in the outer loop and how many iterations are in the inner loop. Then you multiply the two.

The outer loop is simple - i grows from 0 to n-1 in increments of 1, so the total number of iterations is n, which is O(n).

In the inner loop j grows from 1 to n-1, but j is multiplied by 2 in each iteration. If n=2^k, for some integer k, there would be k iterations, and log n = k. Therefore there are O(log n) iterations in the inner loop.

Multiplying the two, you get O(n)*O(log(n)) = O(n log(n));

Answer (score 0):

`O(n Log n)`. Why?

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){       // n
        for(int j=1; j<n; j=j*2){ //Log n (multiplying by 2)
           System.out.println(i*j);
         }
       }`
```

Comment: i had literally no idea how to do this and i have a test over this stuff tomorrow

Comment: wait how would you get log?

Comment: @Lol - Note : Its log n to the base 2. BTW Look at *Eran's* detailed answer to get better understanding.

Comment: @TheLostMind With O(log n) it doesn't actually matter what the base is (because log[base b1] n = C * log[base b2] n for any bases b1, b2, where C is some constant).

Comment: @ajb - I agree. It doesn't matter. But its no harm in knowing it :P

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may do the following:

[image]